# Struts2 component corrupts non-english characters(Chinese)

Tags: character-encoding, struts2, components

I attempted to create a struts2 component using jsp,and I used UTF-8 header in both jsp pages,but in final result I see that those symbols came corrupted. If I change UTF-8 into GBK,it will be ok,I want to kown the reason why 'UTF-8' doesn't work, thanks!!! Struts version 2.1.8

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"  language="java" import="java.util.*" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>

componentTag.jsp

```
<s:component template="mytemplate.jsp">
    <s:param name="list" value="{'java程序设计','Ajax完全学习手册','Struts2学习手册'"> 
    </s:param>
</s:component>
```

mytemplate.jsp (/WebRoot/template/xhtml)

```
 <div style="background-color:#eeeeee;" >
<b>JSP自定义模板</b><br/>
图书列表：<s:select list="parameters.list"></s:select>
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried using `<%@page pageEncoding="utf-8" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" %>` in mytemplate.jsp? also, are your project sources (files themselves, .jsp, .properties, etc) encoded as utf-8?

Comment: yes i did,and this problem has been solved,it is needed to set the JVM boot parameter -Dfile.encoding,i use MyEclipse,i setted the JVM boot parameter of -Dfile.encoding=utf-8,then it is ok,and thank you for your help(MyEclipse->preferences->servers->chose your version and then chose JDK to set the boot parameters)

Answer (score 0):

set the JVM boot parameter of -Dfile.encoding=utf-8
MyEclipse (MyEclipse->preferences->servers->chose your version and then chose JDK to set the boot parameters)

Comment: I am also get stuck in this problem, but I am using eclipse instead. Could you tell me how to set the param within eclipse?

Comment: 今天才看见，找了下，servers view下有你新建的这个tomcat 双击会出现一个视图设置， 然后有个左上方open launch configuration 点击弹出的框里面的arguments选项卡 应该就是了

Answer (score 0):

you may try add these to your struts.xml

```
struts.locale=zh_CN
struts.i18n.encoding=UTF-8
```

if not specified in struts.xml or struts.properties
struts2 will pick the encoding of your platform(of widows it is gbk by default)

很高兴遇见你

Comment: Thank you!（试过你这个了，但是没起作用,我试过所有纠正编码的地方，只有改变了jvm的-Dfile.encoding参数后才起作用）也很高兴遇见你啊，哈哈.